# sh bash script ambiguous redirect pid of file using single quotes

Tags: centos, bash, su, pid, sh

I have the following new line in my .sh file

```
su --session-command='$javaCommandLine & >>$serviceLogFile 2>&1 & echo \$! >$pidFile' $serviceUser || return 1
```

When I had it with double quotes it somewhat worked but the pidFile had the wrong pid it was off by one. The solution from research was to use single quotes and I can't get single quotes to work.

I get now 2 errors

> bash: $pidFile: ambiguous redirect
>   bash: $serviceLogFile: ambiguous redirect

Seems I can't use variables or output to variables in single quotes?

This line almost works but the pid is off by one
This code below would start from boot up but the pid is wrong.

```
su --session-command="$javaCommandLine & >>$serviceLogFile 2>&1 & echo \$! >$pidFile" $serviceUser || return 1
```

which had to replace this buggy old 2 line code.

```
cmd="nohup $javaCommandLine >>$serviceLogFile 2>&1 & echo \$! >$pidFile"
# Don't forget to add -H so the HOME environment variable will be set correctly.
sudo -u $serviceUser -H $SHELL -c "$cmd" || return 1
```

Old code worked fine but it couldn't be started from boot up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process ID is off by one because you have put an extra `&` after the `$javaCommandLine`. In other words, you have put two processes in the background before calling `echo $!`, thus getting the PID of `>>$serviceLogFile 2>&1` rather than `$javaCommandLine`. Those two pieces should be put in one, as the old 2 line codes shows

```
 su --session-command="$javaCommandLine & >>$serviceLogFile 2>&1 & echo \$! >$pidFile" $serviceUser || return 1
```

You might need to change it to -

```
 su --session-command="$javaCommandLine >>$serviceLogFile 2>&1 & echo \$! >$pidFile" $serviceUser || return 1
```

Comment: omg so simple and I was struggling looking all over the place for a solution! TYVM